# how to swap 2 numbers using regexp in vim

Tags: regex, vim, numbers, swap

i have some hardcoded data that looks like this:

```
s1 = [ ...
  [-225.053,-74.050,4.801]' ...
  [-82.053,68.950,4.801]' ...
  [-82.053,-74.050,4.801]' ...
  [-82.053,-217.050,4.801]' ...
  [60.947,-74.050,4.801]' ...
  ];
```

i've got a bunch of those entries. i realized that the first 2 entries of each vector were in the incorrect order, so rather than [a,b,c] it should be [b,a,c].

i want the code to be clear, so i'd like to swap the hardcoded values.
how do i swap the values in vim using regexp?

Answer (score 1):

found a solution. the following will work assuming there are no spaces:

```
s/\(\-\?\d\+\.\d\+\),\(\-\?\d\+\.\d\+\),\(\-\?\d\+\.\d\+\)/\2,\1,\3/gc
```

that's 3 times this:

```
\(\-\?\d\+\.\d\+\)
```

which matches a number of the form `[optional sign]a.b`

Comment: Alternative could be `g/  \[/norm wldf,f,p`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should know how to swap two values.

```
:%s/\(123\),\(456\)/\2,\1/
```

Secondly, you should replace to the correct regular expression.

```
[-225.053,-74.050,4.801]
```

these number split by ","  so you can use this

```
\[\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)\]
```

So, finally, the regular expression is

```
:%s/\[\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)\]/[\3,\1,\2]/
```